# Two has_many :through associations with same models and RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-admin

I have 2 models `Event` and `User` and two models for `:through` associations - `event_member` and `event_organizer`. I create few assocaitions, and in regular use it works, but in rails admin on Events and Event Organizer page I have an error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError in RailsAdmin
>   Association named 'event' was not found on EventOrganizer

When I change associations I start to get other RailsAdmin errors

schema.rb:

```
#event_members
 t.bigint "member_id"
 t.bigint "event_id"
#event_organizers
 t.bigint "organizer_id"
 t.bigint "organized_event_id"
```

In models I have next code:

Event

```
has_many :event_members
has_many :members, through: :event_members, source: :user

has_many :event_organizers
has_many :organizer, through: :event_organizers, source: :user
```

User

```
has_many :event_members, foreign_key: :member_id
has_many :events, through: :event_members

has_many :event_organizers, foreign_key: :organizer_id
has_many :events, through: :event_organizers, source: :user
```

EventOrganizer

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :organizer_id
belongs_to :event, foreign_key: :organized_event_id
```

EventMember

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :member_id
belongs_to :event
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two definitions of `has_many :events` in `User`, and should change their names to make them unique and meaningful.

Comment: I change it to  has_many :ogranized_event, through: :event_organizers, source: :event` and now have another error: Association named 'event'was not found on EventOrganizer

Answer (score 0):

It was dummy problem with wrong scope, it was:

```
has_many :ogranized_event, through: :event_organizers, source: :event
```

Must be:

```
 has_many :event_organized, through: :event_organizers, source: :organized_event
```